# Laravel 5.7 OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

Tags: laravel, facebook, ssl-certificate

I am using following code to get the users detail in my REST API:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
            $response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['query' => [
            'access_token' =>$input['facebook_token'], 
            'fields' => 'id,name,location,gender,email,picture,birthday,link,first_name,last_name'
            ]]);
$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

It was working fine few days ago but now its throwing error :

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": [],
    "data": "cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
}
```

I have Made my virtual host on ssl but still not working any idea ?

Comment: I started having this problem yesterday, and I don’t think I’d make any changes to code recently. Mine says LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL. How did you solve yours?

Comment: @Ryan Actually you need a working domain, it does not work on the localhost.